# Logic behind pre-trained weights and transfer learning

Tags: neural-network, classification, object-detection, transfer-learning, pretraining

I am not sure about the logic behind how pre-trained weights make sense and translate into a new problem.

To be more specific; for example, in a **object detection network**, how would a model's weights that were trained, let's say, on the COCO dataset, with **80 categories**, would translate into my new problem that only has **2 categories (classes)**.
How does this make sense? What kind of meaningful features could even be transferred from the previously pre-trained model to my new problem since the **number of categories (classes)** has been changed, and I'm trying to detect completely **different types of objects** than the previous model? Why do we do transfer learning, then?

Answer (score 1):

*If we classify new objects using transfer learning:*

1. We delete the top *Dense* layer of the pre-trained neural network.
2. Now suppose you have to classify 5 classes, so your final dense layer will contain 5 nodes.
3. Also you will add some dense layers prior to your new 5 nodes Dense layer, so that you can train the model with new data.
4. All the layers prior to the few dense layers you added will be frozen.
5. Now you will train your new model with your dataset.

---

*The Logic behind these steps is:*

1. As **CNN** uses hierarchical-based learning, meaning the initial layers will try to learn basics features in a dataset ie. *lines, corners, shapes, etc*. So the frozen layers of your model have already learned the basic features which are common to your dataset as well as the dataset it has been previously trained on.
2. The few Dense layers you added, will try to learn high-level features specific to your dataset when you train your model with your dataset.

Comment: good information at the _operational_ level

Answer (score 1):

In the case of CNN, you are correct that you cannot use the final layer weights if the number of categories is different. But you CAN reuse the weights in the initial layers. These recognise the lower-level objects in the image. There is no need to train all over again. You would only have to train the upper layers specific to the categorisation you want to do. So transfer learning helps the lower layers in the case of CNN.

Let me give one more example. Say there is a trained model to recognize 100 categories of objects, including animals, plants, buildings, vehicles, etc. You want only to categorize vehicles. You could use the lower layers of the above model as-is and then add a couple of layers at the top, which learn the exact types of vehicle categorization.

In the case of word embedding, the concept of transfer learning is more intuitive and may help understand the concept better. You can train a model on the entire Wikipedia and enable it to learn embeddings for the representation of words. These representations can then directly be used in other models - e.g., tweet sentiment classification, etc. BERT is one such pertained dataset of embeddings. It is a classic case of transfer learning. You no longer have to train on volumes of TeraBytes to learn the language embeddings. You can use it off the shelf.

Comment: good explanation at the conceptual level